# Add missing timeframes into a select query (sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I'm using the code (at bottom) to pull timestamps and some other data out of an sql server for the stated day, in order to make a chart, easy stuff.

the query combines time values into 5 minute ranges, so for example all entries 12:00-12:05 would become one result, and show the max values for the applicable columns for that time frame.

The issue i'm running into is that if data is missing, I want the query to come back with blank rows for the missing 5 minute ranges,  Basically without these gaps I need to run a ton of array formulae in excel, which makes this take minutes instead of a second.

so the total example would be:

```
DateTime    Parts_Made  Alarm_Light
2020-06-01 12:03    5   0
2020-06-01 12:07    6   0
2020-06-01 12:23    8   0


Would return

DateTime    Parts_Made  Alarm_Light
2020-06-01 12:05    5   0
2020-06-01 12:10    6   0      
2020-06-01 12:15    6   0    <-- inserted "missing" row could also be 12:10 - 0 -0 or 12:10  null null I can work around whatever we can come up with
2020-06-01 12:20    6   0    <-- "another" missing row
2020-06-01 12:25    8   0
```

My original thought was just to create a table with every possible 5 minute time range in a day and joining it to the result to create the blank lines where there was no data but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in vba/excel.

Query code:

```
 selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDbConn
   selectCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') as Date_Time " & _
    " ,max(Part_Count)-min(Part_Count) as PartsMade" & _
    ", max(Alarm_Light) as Alarmlight" & _
    ", max(PV_Alarm) as Alarm" & _
    " FROM [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport] " & _
    " Where [DateTime]>= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')-0, 0) AND [DateTime]<= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')+24, 0) " & _
    " AND Machine_Number = " & Machvar & " " & _
    " Group BY DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') "
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to construct the timeframes and then `left join` and `group by`:

```
with times as (
      select convert(datetime, 2020-06-01 12:05) as dt, 1 as lev
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 5, dt), lev + 1
      from times
      where lev < 5
     )
select dt.dt,
       max(t.Part_Count)-min(Part_Count) as PartsMade,
       max(t.Alarm_Light) as Alarmlight,
       max(t.PV_Alarm) as Alarm
from times t left join
     [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport] ti
     on ti.datetime >= t.dt and
        ti.datetime < dateadd(minute, 5, t.dt) and
        ti.machine = ?
group by t.dt
order by t.dt;
```

If there are more than 100 times expected, then add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, Ive been hitting my head against this a bit

I'm getting "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." on the first query (with times as)  with it originally having problems with the date/time listed there.

Since I don't really understand whats going on there in the first few lines could you provide a little more guidance?